# Get names from foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join

For my internship I am making a assignment for tournaments in the break (pool billiard, FIFA, darts etc)

I made a database with all the players and a list with games and the winners.

```
Players (p_id PK, name)

Games (g_id PK, player_one FK, player_two FK)

Winners (g_id FK, winner FK)
```

So in games you can pick the players and by winners, you can pick the winner from the players.

How can I show the names of the players in a table instead of the ID of the player?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: `SELECT w.*, p.name FROM Winners w JOIN Players p ON w.winner = p.p_id`

Comment: I tried doing some stuff with join and inner joins that I looked up. I am not the best joiner, but I am not getting the right results.

Comment: **some stuff** is very informative, thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT 
    g.g_id, 
    p1.name as `player_one`, 
    p2.name as `player_two` 
FROM Games g
INNER JOIN Players p1
ON p1.p_id = g.player_one
INNER JOIN Players p2
ON p2.p_id = g.player_two
```

For your games table and

```
SELECT 
    w.g_id, 
    p.name as `winner`
FROM Winners w
INNER JOIN Players p
ON p.p_id = w.winner
```

For your winners table

And to join all three together

```
SELECT
    g.g_id
    ,p1.name AS `player_one`
    ,p2.name AS `player_two`
    ,pw.name AS `winner`
FROM Games g
INNER JOIN Players p1
ON p1.p_id = g.player_one
INNER JOIN Players p2
ON p2.p_id = g.player_two
LEFT JOIN Winners w
ON w.g_id = g.g_id
LEFT JOIN Players pw
ON pw.p_id = w.winner
```